# An issue about pointer type that is expected as the type of an operand of the operator prefix++ (also for postfix ++)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What types will be expected to be the type of operands of prefix++ is defined as the following:

> The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type other than cv bool, or a **pointer to a completely-defined object type**.

The formal definition for wording `object type`  is defined as:
[basic.types#general-8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-8)

> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is **not a function type**, **not a reference type**, and **not cv void**.

However, consider the below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Test{
  int a;
};
int main(){
 int Test::* member_ptr = &Test::a;
 ++member_ptr;  // Permite this operation?
}
```

According to the definition of `object type`, `member type` is not be excluded by it. Does it mean we could consider `member type` to be an `object type`? you will say, `members` are not objects, so the `pointer to member` cannot be used as the operand of prefix++. But, I will argue here, Is a function an object? That's absolutely not, why `function type` is excluded by the definition for `object type`, also `reference type`. So, Is it a defect that didn't place a `member type` to the exclusive set?

#### UPDATE

The answers from M.M quotes the rule:

> Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members.

I know that rule. However, I thought the `pointers` just refers to literal `pointers`. After all, the text `pointers` has appeared in the standard. Such as: [expr.eq#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#2)  Comparing **pointers** is defined as follows. (The rule can absolutely be applied here, that is, does not apply to pointers to members). However, I don't think the text `pointers` also denotes the form `pointer to X`(where X is anything other than `member`,e.g `object`, `function`). Is it necessary to clarify that rule?

> Except describes anywhere, `pointer to X`(where X may be object, function, or type) or `pointers` does not apply to `pointer to member`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `member type`

Comment: Unless explicitly mentioned, "pointers" exclude member pointers.

Comment: @M.M That might be `class nested-name-specifier of type T`. (however, such stuff is not permitted as a type-specifier).

Comment: @PasserBy Yup, I know [that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3). However, here it refers to `pointer to object type`.

Answer (score 4):

See [[basic.compound]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3):

> Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members.

So in the first text you quote, "pointer to a completely-defined object type" excludes the possibility of pointers to members.  So `++` cannot be applied to a pointer-to-member.

Comment: Does that sentence mean, `pointer to something` does not consider `pointer to member`, except that the text is explicit `pointer to member`? I thought that sentence does mean literal `pointers`.

Comment: @jackX This seems to be a recurring theme in your questions, asking for clarification on the English. _"text referring to “pointers”"_ really just mean whenever we talk about pointers.

Comment: @PasserBy That's the question itself.  The text `pointers` has appeared in the standard, such as "Comparing pointers is defined as follows".  I thought `pointers` just refer to the appearance like this. I don't think that the text `pointers` also indicates the form `pointer to X`(where X is not member).

Comment: @jackX With exception of pointers to static members, anytime you see `pointer` in general, it does not refer to pointers to members. The text *pointer to a completely-defined object type* does NOT encompass pointers to members, because it doesn't explicitly mention them. Clear? I really don't see what the big deal is. The phrase *pointer to something* obviously refers to a **pointer**, right? The "to something" is just an additional qualification, and what's meant here is that the qualification cannot be understood to encompass nonstatic  member pointers unless it's literally stated so.

Comment: @jackX Another way to think about it is: anytime you see *pointer* or *pointer to something*, then whatever you think the something may be, it's never a non-static member, unless it's literally stated "pointer to a non-static member function".

Comment: @UnslanderMonica "what's meant here is that the qualification cannot be understood to encompass nonstatic member pointers unless it's literally stated so. " A precise description.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica what will make a misunderstanding in that rule is the wording **text referring to “pointers”**. The wording seems to say when we see the **text** `pointers` in the standard, just consider anything other than `pointer to member`.

Comment: @jackX Precisely, but you were arguing an opposite of that, right?

Comment: @UnslanderMonica  Please take a look at the comment under the answers of Unslander Monica. That's what I am concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever my kids have trouble understanding a complex mathematical expression I tell them this: OK, you know that this expression is all about numbers. So try and substitute some numbers for certain sub-expressions, and see if that makes it easier to operate on it. Once you get comfortable with `5` in place of `sin(x)` and `5/10` in place of `tan(x)`, then switch back. I've had considerable success with this when fancier explanatory options have ran out. (I can't think of any actual examples of formulas we used that on - sorry, I'll edit the question later, potentially months or years later, when something comes to mind).

So, let's do this with the C++ standard. Per [[basic.compound]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3):

> Except for blue speckled eggs, text referring to “eggs” does not apply to blue eggs.

Then you quote:

> The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type other than cv bool, or a colorful egg.

That egg cannot be blue, unless of course it'd be literally stated to apply to blue eggs.

> However, I don't think the text eggs also denotes the form egg of color X.

Well. If this was about eggs, you would think otherwise, right? And there is clearly a decent homomorphism between and poultry husbandry and C++ :)

- Egg = pointer
- Blue egg = pointer to a member (in general)
- Blue speckled egg = pointer to a static member
- Colorful egg = pointer to a fully defined object type
- Plain (colorless egg = pointer to a not fully defined object type

Sorta-kinda like that :)

Sometimes, it really is worth substituting homomorphic classes of objects that you're familiar with (I assume you're familiar with eggs, if not - pencils work well, too). Things just don't sound so weird then, and I completely appreciate that it's hard to think of the C++ standard as if it pertained to some familiar objects. Just pretend you're familiar with them and keep going.

Comment: I know what you mean. what will make a misunderstanding in that rule is the wording `text referring to “pointers”`. The wording seems to say when we see the text pointers in the standard, just consider anything other than a pointer to member. In other words, whether `pointers` here is considered as a concept(a set of pointers) or just a text.  what I'm concerned about here is, the wording `text pointers`.

Comment: For example, when I ask you to replace the keyword text `animal` with `X` for this sentence: `a tiger, a monkey, a lion, and other animals`. Do I ask you to replace anything that is an animal or just the text "animal"? That's vague.